# MySQL Large DELETE with JOINs

Tags: mysql, delete, amazon-rds

I have a large table `players` with ~20MM rows which joins to a table `stats` with ~300MM rows, among others (`photos`, ...).  I want to DELETE all records for `players` that were `born_on` before 1950.  I should mention this is a Rails app, so I haven't properly constrained any of these relations with Foreign Keys (and I have a good number of indices on each of these tables, listed at the bottom).

[**Edit**] I would also like to delete all related data from stats, photos, etc.  All-in-all, I would like to delete associations from about 10 tables, some of which are second-degree

I would expect to delete the players with a query like so [**updated**]:

```
DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"
```

But, I'm running into an issue that that query, as it's a huge delete, is taking significantly too long and too many resources to complete [ever].  As I'm running the query with a JOIN, MySQL won't let me limit the DELETE to break the query into chunks.

Alternatively, I've tried deleting each row separately:

```
SELECT id FROM "players" where "players".born_on < "1950-01-01";
```

Then

```
DELETE FROM "players" WHERE "players".id = 5;
DELETE FROM "stats" WHERE "stats".player_id = 5;
DELETE FROM "photos" WHERE "photos".player_id = 5;
... repeat
```

But the amount of parallelization necessary to complete these on say 10MM rows also throttles the database to 100% CPU (running m1.xlarge on Amazon RDS), rendering complete downtime for what would be several days of query.

My question is, what is the best way to delete these old rows from the database without incurring significant downtime for my application.  Are there settings that could help, etc. that would make this simple and effective.

Please feel free to ask more questions about configuration, etc. as necessary to solve this problem.  Thanks in advance for all of your help!

[**Edit**]

## Schema

**Players Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `birth_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jersey_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coach_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `players_team_id_last_name` (`team_id`,`last_name`),
  KEY `players_jersey_name` (`jersey_name`),
  KEY `players_home_city` (`home_city`),
  KEY `players_coach_id_index` (`coach_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=611 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

**Stats Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `player_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bucket_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(4096) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta1` longtext,
  `meta2` longtext,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confidence` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `viewed_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `view_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `reported_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `reserved` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `ref_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `stats_player_id_bucket_id` (`player_id`,`bucket_id`),
  KEY `stats_ref_id_player_id_bucket_id` (`ref_id`,`player_id`,`bucket_id`),
  KEY `stats_status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10322 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

**Photos Table**

```
CREATE TABLE `photos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `player_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` text,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `photo_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lon` decimal(15,10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `caption` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `place_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `href` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `photos_player_id` (`player_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=313 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
```

Comment: @ypercube, thanks.  I wrote this up late at night.  I've fixed the query syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL there is a multi-table [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html) syntax. Your first DELETE will delete rows only from the `players` TABLE. If you want to delete from multiple tables you have to use something like:

```
DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"
```

This doesn't address the problem with the long-running DELETE statement though. In fact above query should take even more time, because now it actually would delete rows from `stats` and `photos` tables. The workaround you could use is to split the large DELETE into smaller ones. Since you have a nice WHERE condition, you could manually split the deletes on that (for example one DELETE for each ten years of `players.born_on`) and run them in ascending order, that is:

```
DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1930-01-01";

DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1940-01-01";

DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01";
```

It this is too coarse (i.e. it takes too long do execute each query) you should make the WHERE conditions even more fine-grained (perhaps delete one year each chunk).

Also there is a `--purge` option for [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-archiver.html) from Percona Toolkit which would split the data to be deleted in chunks automatically, but it doesn't seem to support the multi table case. See example usage of pt-archiver in [this presentation](https://archive.fosdem.org/2013/schedule/event/5_pt/attachments/slides/268/export/events/attachments/5_pt/slides/268/Percona_Toolkit.pdf)

From your table definitions I see that you don't have an index on `players.birth_date` (I suppose that this is the column you relate to as `born_at` in your example queries). This makes the decade chunks approach useless, since every query would have to scan all `players` table.

If you can't afford having a long table lock for the DELETE to finish, you most likely can't afford to create an index on the `birth_date` column as well.

You could split the data on another column, PRIMARY KEY is a good bet. You can write a script which would process all the players in chunks of 10000 (or less or more, depending on the length of a single DELETE statement):

```
DELETE FROM "players","stats","photos"
USING "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"
  AND "players".id BETWEEN n*10000+1 AND (n+1)*10000
```

Where n would be a parameter ranging from 0 to MAX(players.id)/10000 . This way you will avoid a full table scan (which certainly *is* painful for a 100M table)

You could also try to estimate the DELETE complexity with an EXPLAIN SELECT instead of DELETE:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM "players"
  LEFT JOIN "stats"
    ON "players".id = "stats".player_id
  LEFT JOIN "photos"
    ON "players".id = "photos".player_id
WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"
  AND "players".id BETWEEN 1 AND 10000
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I added the clarification that yes, I would like to remove the associated tables.  I like the idea of working it one decade (or possibly, one month) at a time.  Would this require a large lock to do a DELETE?  When I've run this historically (with about 10 JOINs, I believe all generally on keys), I end up with the query held for a long time.  Would that make sense with the schema listed above.  Thanks for your help; really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks for this write-up.  I was able to set better indices for the JOINs and get the DELETE to run in segments using id constraints.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example the JOINs do nothing - the query runner is going to go looking for rows in `stats` and `players` that relate to the rows where `born_on < "1950-01-01"born_on < "1950-01-01"` but then do nothing with that information. Simply using `SELECT id FROM "players" where "players".born_on < "1950-01-01";` would do the same thing.

If you are wanting the related rows in `stats` and `photos` to go (you don;t say as such, but I assume so as you'll have a lot of orphan data otherwise) then you need to either do that with separate statements, or foreign key constrains with `ON DELETE CASCADE` set, or (not recommended) triggers to do the same thing. Simply naming them in the `DELETE` statement for the parent table is not sufficicent to let the query planner know that is what you want.

> so I haven't properly constrained any of these relations

Does this main you have no foreign key constraints? If so then `DELETE FROM "players" WHERE "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"` will work but leave orphan records in `stats` and `photots`. If you have FK constrains with `ON DELETE CASCADE` (or triggers to acheive the same thing) then those newly orphaned rows will be deleted and that might be taking a lot of the time *especially* if the right indexes are not in place (I'm not sure about MySQL, but in MSSQL an FK does not imply that an index exists). If you have FKs without cascaded actions then you'd get referential integrity related errors so I assume that is not the case. Depending on how bright mySQL is or isn't, you might find removing the related rows first rather then relying on cascaded deletes is faster.

> and I have a good number of indices on each of these tables

You need to specify what those indexes are in order for us to kow if that is a good thing or not. Having many indexes will slow delete operations as every index needs to be updated as well as the table's heap or clsutered index, and having lots does not mean you have the right ones to help this particular task.

*You should update the question to provide the specifics of the table structures (all indexes, keys, and constraints that exist) for us to be able to give more specific advice.*

Comment: Thank you for your help here.  I've added the schema and clarified a few points you've listed.  Really appreciate the feedback you've given.

Answer (score 1):

In your attempt:

> ```
> SELECT id FROM "players" where "players".born_on < "1950-01-01"; Then
>  DELETE FROM "players" WHERE "players".id = 5;
>  DELETE FROM "stats" WHERE "stats".player_id = 5;
>  DELETE FROM "photos" WHERE "photos".player_id = 5; ... repeat
> ```

First, I don't understand the "...= 5;" one each the subsequent deletes. What is the 5?

But....what if you created a temporary table from the SELECT id that just has id as a column, then proceeded with your DELETES.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS partials (SELECT id FROM "players" where "players".born_on < "1950-01-01" limit 10000)

and now

SELECT id FROM "partials";
   DELETE FROM "players" WHERE "players".id = ...
```

You could then use a limit statement on building your temporary table.

Comment: Was meant to be the list of ids stored in memory by the application calling the SQL.  I like your use of a temp table for this purpose.  Thanks.